# I am unable to run a shell script using ex (VIM)?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, script

`$ ex -sc $'%s/\r$//e|x' file` Perfectly works from the terminal from but when I try to run it with `.sh` script it simply ignores the lines after `ex`.

```
$ rm ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf81.csv    
$ rm ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf8.csv

$ cat ~/Desktop/projectautomate/headersutf8.csv ~/Desktop/projectautomate/upload.csv >> ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf8.csv


$ iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf8.csv -o ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf81.csv -c
$ ex -sc $'%s/\r$//e|x' ~/Desktop/projectautomate/finalutf81.csv
```

Every thing works but not the last line of command. 
I am basically trying to remove the CRLF (end line control characters) from the the file finalutf8.csv .
Some detailed explanations would be appreciated. If not clear as English is my second language, I would try to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are these `$` for?

```
#!/bin/sh
ex -sc '%s/\r//e|x' toto.txt
```

seems to work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks it works. some one in some blogs suggested to add `$` before the codes. I am not sure if people use it here or not. Did't knew about `#!/bin/sh`. what is is actually for? Seems like `#`commented out but again it works.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is used to tell your shell how it is supposed to interpret your script [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). You should put it on the 1st line of your shell script.

Comment: Thanks, that was important to know for many other uses as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$''` is a bash thing only; the shell script is probably being executed with sh or dash. Put

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the first line.